# iloc - IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds") even though it's within the bounds

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the rows from specific indexes (these indexes are in a list). I keep getting an IndexError even though these indexes (ones in the list) are within the range

The df has an index count of **10872** (with the highest value being 2600)
The list has a count of 628 (with the highest value being 2500)

```
list = df.loc[df[col] == value].index.tolist
df.iloc[[list]]
```

I want to print out the data then eventually get the next 4 rows from each of the specific indices

Comment: Why don't you just do `df[df[col]==value]` this will give you the same data in less steps

Comment: If I do that, I get an empty dataset

Answer (score 3):

Here you should not using `.iloc` for index , `.iloc` is for the position and , `loc` is for the index

So in your case you should

```
l= df.loc[df[col] == value].index.tolist()

df.loc[l]
```

For example

```
df
Out[59]: 
  key
1   1
3   1
4   1
7   2
9   3
```

If you want to get the 1st row with `.iloc` you can

```
df.iloc[[0]]
Out[61]: 
  key
1   1
```

but with `loc`

```
df.loc[[1]]
Out[62]: 
  key
1   1
```

---

The error , when you want the last row , and the index is number 9 , but there is no position 9 for df.

```
df.iloc[9]
```

> ```
> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
> ```

```
df.loc[9]
Out[64]: 
key    3
Name: 9, dtype: object
```